# Undefined method Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, oop, object

I would like to create an array of my custom objects. But when I try to call a method of the one of the objects, I get an error **undefined method `get_id' for #Map:0x000055cf036a0838>**.

Here is my code:

```
maps = []
map = Map.new(id)
maps.push(map)
puts maps[0].get_id
```

Comment: Show the `Map` class definition.

Comment: You might be thinking first, why you did not think whether `Map` class have instance method `get_id`

Comment: @ray I am very sorry for this. I've just started learning Ruby after C/C++. So I in the past I always wrote get_ and set_ names for methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your `Map` class doesn't define `get_id` method. Hint - in Ruby you don't use `get_` and `set_` prefixes, so maybe you just wanted to call `maps[0].id`?

Comment: You are totally right! I've renamed my method to read_id. Thanks!

Comment: It would be more common to write `@id = id` in the `initialize` method, and `attr_reader :id` to create an access method.

Comment: And `def id=(value)` when you need to set the ID from outside (you'll put some verification on value to ensure id always has allowed values).

Comment: And in future, I'd strongly recommend aiming to write a [mcve] when posting questions on StackOverflow. Your question is not reproducible, since you did not show us the definition of the `Map` class.